# IUrlHistoryStg2::ClearHistory() does not work from a service?

Tags: url, com, browser-history

The IUrlHistoryStg2::ClearHistory() method is documented as Per-User.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767715(VS.85).aspx

When calling it from a service running under the SYSTEM account, I am unable to target particular logged-on users. I have successfully impersonated the users via WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() but the call to ClearHistory() always returns 0 for success but does not clear the history of the user.

This applies on both XP and Win7 so appears to be not a session isolation issue.

Perhaps because it is COM, something is looking at the Process token of the caller rather than its Thread token when impersonating?

I am confused why impersonating the user does not simply lead to success of this method?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/**
* wrapper for IUrlHistory
*/
public struct STATURL
{
    public static uint SIZEOF_STATURL = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf( typeof(STATURL) );
    public uint cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string pwcsUrl;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string pwcsTitle;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
                ftLastVisited,
                ftLastUpdated,
                ftExpires;
    public uint dwFlags;
}

[ComImport, Guid("3C374A42-BAE4-11CF-BF7D-00AA006946EE"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IEnumSTATURL
{
    [PreserveSig]
    uint Next(uint celt, out STATURL rgelt, out uint pceltFetched);
    void Skip(uint celt);
    void Reset();
    void Clone(out IEnumSTATURL ppenum);
    void SetFilter(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string poszFilter,
        uint dwFlags);
}

[ComImport, Guid("AFA0DC11-C313-11d0-831A-00C04FD5AE38"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IUrlHistoryStg2
{
    #region IUrlHistoryStg methods
    void AddUrl(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsTitle,
        uint dwFlags);

    void DeleteUrl(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsUrl,
        uint dwFlags);

    void QueryUrl(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsUrl,
        uint dwFlags,
        ref STATURL lpSTATURL);

    void BindToObject(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsUrl,
        ref Guid riid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppvOut);

    IEnumSTATURL EnumUrls();

    #endregion

    void AddUrlAndNotify(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pocsTitle,
        uint dwFlags,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fWriteHistory,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object /*IOleCommandTarget*/
        poctNotify,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punkISFolder);

    void ClearHistory();
}

[ComImport, Guid("3C374A40-BAE4-11CF-BF7D-00AA006946EE")]
public class UrlHistory /* : IUrlHistoryStg[2] */ {}


public class test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IUrlHistoryStg2 stg = (IUrlHistoryStg2) new UrlHistory();
        stg.ClearHistory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a service or an application impersonates a user, the system does not load the user's profile. Try call [LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762281%28VS.85%29.aspx) first.

Answer (score 1):

[IUrlHistoryStg2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767716(v=vs.85).aspx) eventually uses the Wininet APIs such as [CommitUrlCacheEntryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384270(v=vs.85).aspx)

Microsoft documentation states that:

> Like all other aspects of the WinINet API, this function cannot be
>   safely called from within DllMain or the constructors and destructors
>   of global objects. Note  WinINet does not support server
>   implementations. In addition, it should not be used from a service.
>   For server implementations or services use Microsoft Windows HTTP
>   Services (WinHTTP).

I reversed those API and found out the they have check for

- Impersonation
- Running from a service

If either is true, the API exists with error code 0x80070078

So, fortunately what you are trying to achieve  is not possible from a service and you must use [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx)