# My C# browser shows some of it's history in IE's history

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser-history

after browsing in my c# browser, atleast half the history is shown in the IE browser history.

is there a way of preventing this? 
also, how wouuld i get any popups to show in my broswer not IE?
thanks

Comment: What is a "C# browser"? The C# programming language does not have a browser.

Comment: In all likelihood, you are using "internet explorer" within a form control.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` Windows Forms control uses Internet Explorer. You'll have to check the documentation for that class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to see if there's a way to prevent it from storing history.

Comment: I think you'll have to P/Invoke to prevent WebBrowser from retrieving the user's history. I don't know any native method equivalent to that of InternetSetOption(..) in "wininet.dll"

Comment: @Cody Gray, it's a web browser i created in C#. sorry for confusion, it's my first project, ever.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually using Internet Explorer, just without the frame window.  It doesn't have an option to selectively enable history recording.

You don't have attractive options here.  The IUrlHistoryStg2 interface lets you manipulate the browser history.  Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305757/iurlhistorystg2clearhistory-does-not-work-from-a-service) for the declarations you will need.  While the DeleteUrl() method would be the obvious choice, it doesn't actually work as documented in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327569).

Which leaves but the heavy hammer, ClearHistory().  Actually using it might inspire the user to switch to another browser, another way to solve the problem.